# Microsoft teams configuration tab renders in browser but not native macOS app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm working on a Microsoft Teams tab app. When installing my app in their web client, I'm able to successfully load my tab configuration page. Repeating this workflow in the macOS client fails with nothing being rendered. With Electron logging enabled, I'm seeing the following output:

`[2998:0828/101101.014965:INFO:CONSOLE(113)] "Controller 'kbList' or 'kbSelect', required by directive 'kbItem', can't be found!", source: https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/hashedjs/0-angular-jquery.min-dafbbdf5.js (113)
[2998:0828/101101.151096:INFO:CONSOLE(76)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'prefetch-src'.
", source: https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/hashedjs/0-angular-jquery.min-dafbbdf5.js (76)
[2998:0828/101101.151309:INFO:CONSOLE(76)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'prefetch-src'.
", source: https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/hashedjs/0-angular-jquery.min-dafbbdf5.js (76)
[2998:0828/101101.223595:INFO:CONSOLE(76)] "Uncaught (in promise) undefined", source: https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/hashedjs/0-angular-jquery.min-dafbbdf5.js (76)
[2998:0828/101101.223676:INFO:CONSOLE(76)] "Uncaught (in promise) undefined", source: https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/hashedjs/0-angular-jquery.min-dafbbdf5.js (76)
[2998:0828/101101.400452:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/conversations/General?threadId=19:c63e6abc4e4b4474a991c921adf0ce77@thread.skype&ctx=channel (0)
[2998:0828/101101.469231:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/conversations/General?threadId=19:c63e6abc4e4b4474a991c921adf0ce77@thread.skype&ctx=channel (0)`

It looks like my rails app is never actually getting the request for the iframed content as nothing is logged.

Comment: What are your HTTP header settings? In particular see the comment on `Content-Security-Policy` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-requirements)

Comment: `Content-Security-Policy: default-src https: 'self'; font-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com; img-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' *.walkme.com *.logrocket.io *.google-analytics.com ajax.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'`

Comment: @AlexanderKron I think you want the logs from your tab, not the Teams app. Try the instructions here to show the DevTools window for your tab: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-tools

Comment: @AdrianSolis I'm seeing the same logs there but it's definitely helpful to know those exist. I'll see if I can get more info using the dev tools

Answer (score 0):

I was running my app locally and didn't realize that the native client needed an externally accessible URI. Using ngrok solved my issue

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/general/debug#locally-hosted